# Full viewport element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying come up with how to get a fullscreen intro element that cover 100 of the viewport in any size of the browser window? And when you start scrolling, you can see the rest of the homepage. Please have a look at the example link below.

https://mtrexpress.se/sv

They are using a movie, but I'm just interested in a simple div and use a background image that cover the screen. I have tried to analyze the webpage, and I guess they are not using any background poperties, instead just a div with different layers? Would be interesting to learn how this is done.

I made a simple test, and I filled it with lot of dummy text(I removed all the text before I pasted the code here), but i seems like the intre div stays fullscreen and I can't scroll to the rest of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#intro {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="intro">Intro</div>
<div class="container">Page content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing full *screen* and full *viewport*

Comment: @Quentin I guess I'm looking for full viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**viewport percentage lengths**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths), `vw` and `vh`

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of
>   viewport, that is the visible portion of the document. Only
>   Gecko-based browsers are updating the viewport values dynamically,
>   when the size of the viewport is modified (by modifying the size of
>   the window on a desktop computer or by turning the device on a phone
>   or a tablet).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width:100%;  /* prevent horizontal scrollbars */
  background: blue;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works just like I want, but does this only works in Firefox!? Any other solution that also works in other browsers?

Comment: I'll have you know that dynamic adaptation of the height with `vh` works well in Chrome **44.0.2403.125 m**

Comment: @3D-kreativ - see: http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport, there shouldnt be any compatability issues

Comment: I get a horizontal scroll bar in the bottom of the browser. I used overflow-x, but it's still there!?

Comment: Simply add `max-width:100%;` (see updated code above)

Comment: Yes I just tested that and was going to write that I had fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oops! I just discovered that I get a double vertical scrollbar now!?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}

.intro {
  height : 100vh;
  background-color : lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro"></div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in erat et erat malesuada iaculis vel vel     nisl. Nam nunc sapien, sodales a mauris nec, faucibus aliquet elit. Suspendisse et euismod justo, vel blandit nulla. In sodales vehicula sodales. Mauris tincidunt dui justo, nec finibus purus euismod sed. Pellentesque rutrum posuere velit, sit amet sollicitudin tellus semper a. Curabitur auctor consequat quam, at aliquam felis feugiat non. In tincidunt suscipit feugiat. Etiam at nunc nec nunc fermentum tristique ut ac elit. Quisque lacinia tellus vitae dignissim pellentesque. Vivamus in sodales diam, eget posuere dui. Sed ac eros finibus, sodales sem eu, elementum libero. Nullam fringilla nec eros vel tincidunt. Vestibulum vel dolor ornare, tincidunt risus in, pretium tortor.
</div>
```

The example above show the usage of `vh` CSS3 height rule. 
As you can see it only require to set the height to `height : 100vh`, which means *take 100% of the **V**iewport **H**eight* of the screen (the screen is named the "Viewport").

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) which gives compatibility information for web components, you have a **IE9+** and **Android 4.3+** compatiblity for the minimum required devices (in other words, quite recents devices).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use *viewport percentage lengths* you could do something like the following.

It is a bit repetitive, because you would have to set the `top` position of each content section, but it will work without the use of `vh` even in IE7.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  position:fixed !important;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#intro {
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div[class*="content"] {
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-page-1 {
  background: green;
  top: 100%;
}
.content-page-2 {
  background: yellow;
  top: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="intro">
    Intro
  </div>
  <div class="content-page-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore temporibus ex magni nesciunt quasi illo sit aliquam unde! Molestias iusto perferendis nulla voluptatum illo non numquam impedit consequuntur sunt a!
  </div>
  <div class="content-page-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore temporibus ex magni nesciunt quasi illo sit aliquam unde! Molestias iusto perferendis nulla voluptatum illo non numquam impedit consequuntur sunt a!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u set Height:100%; you canot scroll, instead of height:100% put height:auto; based on text it will occupy.

or

If u remove Height:100%; also it will work.

or

```
#intro{height:50%;}
.container{height:50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `vh` with `calc()` function. VH take 100% height of browser and we have header also so you can reduce height of header via `calc`
 please add css

```css
#top{
  calc(100vh - 71px)  
}
```

Hope this code will work for you